# "him arriving and me finishing the wine"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, noun-phrases

I copied the below sentence from one of the answers to another question:

> This means that he arrived and I quickly finished the last of the wine. The two events (him arriving and me finishing the wine) happened at roughly the same time- both in the past.

Shouldn't we use "**his arriving**" instead of "**him arriving**"
and
"**my finishing the wine**" instead of "**me finishing the wine**"

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use the word *"remember (a thinking verb)"* to provide good examples, and hopefully have you understand this unit of grammar.

> I remember him arriving. ( where "him" functions as an object );
>
> I remember his arriving. ( where "his" is the possessive - relies on more formal usage, and it is more identical to
> *"his arrival*" but not necessarily );

Well, there is no difference in both whatsoever as we are talking about instances of gerunds ( -ing forms of verbs ) and not about NOUNS per se. So which one you will use depends on your personal opinion and preference.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is incorrect.  You can say "I remember him arriving" or "I remember his arriving".  You can't say "I remember he arriving".

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention to my autocorrect.